# Why After hitting the refresh button, the value of quantities, incremented by one?

Tags: php

```
<?php       
    foreach ($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $item){
        ?>
                <tr>
                <td style="text-align:left;border-bottom:#F0F0F0 1px solid;"><strong><?php echo $item["nama_produk"]; ?></strong></td>
                <td style="text-align:left;border-bottom:#F0F0F0 1px solid;"><?php echo $item["id_produk"]; ?></td>
                <td style="text-align:right;border-bottom:#F0F0F0 1px solid;"><input type="text" name="quantity" value="<?php echo $item['quantity']; ?>" style="width: 50px"></td>
                <td style="text-align:right;border-bottom:#F0F0F0 1px solid;"><?php echo "Rp. ".$item["harga_produk"]; ?></td>
                <td style="text-align:center;border-bottom:#F0F0F0 1px solid;"><a href="cart.php?action=remove&id_produk=<?php echo $item["id_produk"]; ?>" class="btnRemoveAction">Remove Item</a></td>
                </tr>
                <?php
        $item_total += ($item["harga_produk"]*$item["quantity"]);
        }
        ?>
```

Why After hitting the refresh button, the value of quantities, incremented by one?
This is the cart item SESSION:

```
if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
                if(in_array($productByCode[0]["id_produk"],array_keys($_SESSION["cart_item"]))) {
                    foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
                            if($productByCode[0]["id_produk"] == $k) {
                                if(empty($_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"])) {
                                    $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] = 0;}
                                $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] += $_POST["quantity"];}}} else {
                    $_SESSION["cart_item"] = array_merge($_SESSION["cart_item"],$itemArray);
                }
            } else {
                $_SESSION["cart_item"] = $itemArray;}}
```

[image: before refresh]

[image: after refresh]

Comment: if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) {
    if(in_array($productByCode[0]["id_produk"],array_keys($_SESSION["cart_item"]))) {
     foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) {
       if($productByCode[0]["id_produk"] == $k) {
        if(empty($_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"])) {
         $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] = 0;
        }
        $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] += $_POST["quantity"];
       }
     }
    } else {
     $_SESSION["cart_item"] = array_merge($_SESSION["cart_item"],$itemArray);
 }
} else {
$_SESSION["cart_item"] = $itemArray;
}
}
break;

Comment: I mean it's so. always add after refresh.

Comment: yes i send it to url action="cart.php?action=add&id_produk=

Comment: Ok - time to stop having a conversation here in comments - that's not what comments are for.  Additional info for the question should be added to the question *as an edit*. Way too much back-n-forth going on. Take this to [chat]

Answer (score -2):

check  $_SESSION["cart_item"]  value in your script flow

Comment: This doesn't look like an answer, but this section is only for answers. Once you have earned 50 reputation points you'll be able to comment; until then, please ask and answer questions to earn reputation.

Comment: if(!empty($_SESSION["cart_item"])) { if(in_array($productByCode[0]["id_produk"],array_keys($_‌​SESSION["cart_item"]‌​))) { foreach($_SESSION["cart_item"] as $k => $v) { if($productByCode[0]["id_produk"] == $k) { if(empty($_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"])) { $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] = 0; } $_SESSION["cart_item"][$k]["quantity"] += $_POST["quantity"]; } } } else { $_SESSION["cart_item"] = array_merge($_SESSION["cart_item"],$itemArray); } } else { $_SESSION["cart_item"] = $itemArray; } } break;

Comment: @Muh.RezkyAnugerah.A - please do *not* dump content like that into a comment. Impossible to read. If you have updates to your question, *edit your question.* **Note** - someone already stated the exact same thing to you, in your comment below your question. Same exact situation, same 100% unreadable content dump.